# Is there a documented API for supporting the new Google Hangouts features so I can create a Hangout app for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, google-plus

I see the Hangouts API here, but it talks about creating an app that would integrate with the Google+ webapp.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout?hl=en

I'm looking to create a client so Windows Phone users can chat with their friends on other platforms as well, but can't find too much information on how to get started here.

The quick start for .NET/C# doesn't really help much for this either. I was able to get the PeopleFeed but there is no mention of a list of current hangouts, start a new hangout, etc... Did they not make this public yet? Will they ever?

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp#step_1_enable_the_google_api

Answer (score 4):

There currently are not Google+ libraries that will work on Windows Phone and the API currently does not support starting hangouts. You can request these features from [the Google+ Developers issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/).